# How Numeric types are defined in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, int

I am new to haskell.

Is Int defined as

```
data Int8 = (-128) | (-127) | (-126) | ..... | 0 | ..... | 126 | 127
```

then How about

```
data Integer = ?
```

& how instance of Num Int is created

```
instance Num Int8 where
   1 + 2 = 3
   2 + 1 = 3
   -- All permutation & Combinations?
```

Comment: Well, no.  That's not how various integral types are defined.  The main way you can tell is that constructors are disjoint between types, but `(1 :: Int8)` and `(1 :: Integer)` both are valid.  That directly means that `1` isn't a constructor.

Comment: Types like Int, Integer, Int8 are primitive types, that are built into the compiler (GHC). [This article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/02/primitive-haskell) explains the basics.

Comment: @sjakobi Thanks a lot for the article. That what I was looking for.

Comment: @sjakobi Is there any Free material of haskell from "fpcomplete" guys. If so please provide a link.

Comment: @PKChem You can find more of their articles at https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog. They’re very interesting, but probably not the best resource to learn Haskell from (many of them assume intermediate to advanced Haskell knowledge as a prerequisite).